# Self-contained proof of WO of Buchholz's ordinal notation system

Tags: ordinal-numbers

I would like a self-contained proof that the ordinal notation system defined by Buchholz in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0168-0072(86)90052-7) is indeed well-ordered. Meaning, I would like a proof that does not rely on ordinals. Buchholz's system defines ordinals below $\Psi_0(\Omega_\omega)$.

The system is recursively defined as follows: A *term* is an expression of the form $\beta = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k$, $k\ge 0$, where each $\alpha_i$ is a previously defined *principal term*. A *principal term* is of the form $D_n(\beta)$ for $n\in\mathbb N$, where $D_n$ is just a formal symbol, and $\beta$ is a previously defined term. The term with zero principal terms is denoted $0$.

(Each term can be thought of as an ordered, rooted tree whose edges are labeled with natural numbers. A principal term is then a tree in which the root has a single child.)

Recursively define a binary relation "$<$" on terms and principal terms as follows: Let $\beta = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k$ and $\beta' = \alpha'_1 + \cdots + \alpha'_\ell$ be two terms. Then $\beta<\beta'$ if either $\beta'$ is an extension of $\beta$ (meaning $k<\ell$ and $\alpha_i=\alpha'_i$ for all $i\le k$) or the smallest index $i$ at which $\beta,\beta'$ differ satisfies $\alpha_i<\alpha'_i$. Let $\alpha=D_n(\beta)$ and $\alpha'=D_m(\beta')$ be two principal terms. Then $\alpha<\alpha'$ if either $n<m$, or else $n=m$ and $\beta<\beta'$.

It's easy to show that the relation "$<$" is a total order. However, it is not a well order. For example, $D_1(0)>D_0(0)+D_1(0) > D_0(0)+D_0(0)+D_1(0)> \cdots$. Another example: $D_1(0)>D_0(D_1(0))> D_0(D_0(D_1(0)))>\cdots$.

We now define a subset of terms which we call *ordinal terms* (OT). First we define, for each term $\beta$ and each $n$, a set $G_n(\beta)$ of subterms of $\beta$. Suppose $\beta = \alpha_1 + \cdots + \alpha_k$. Then we define $G_n(\beta) = G_n(\alpha_1) \cup \cdots \cup G_n(\alpha_k)$. For a principal term $\alpha = D_m(\beta)$, we define $G_n(\alpha)$ as $\emptyset$ if $m<n$, and as $\{\beta\}\cup G_n(\beta)$ otherwise.

(If we think of terms as trees, then given a tree $t$ and an integer $n$, we start at the root of $t$. We follow all possible paths towards the leaves, continuing as long as we meet edges labeled $n$ or larger. For each such edge $e$ we take the tree supported by $e$ without $e$ itself. Edges with labels smaller than $n$ serve as no-entry barriers.)

Now, a term $\beta = \alpha_1+\cdots+\alpha_k$ is an *ordinal term* if each $\alpha_i$ is a *principal ordinal term* and $\alpha_1\ge\alpha_2\ge\cdots\ge\alpha_k$. And $\alpha = D_n(\beta)$ is a *principal ordinal term* if $\beta$ is an ordinal term and $\beta'<\beta$ for each $\beta'\in G_n(\beta)$. (Note that here it says $G_n(\beta)$ and not $G_n(\alpha)$.)

So for example, $D_n(D_m(0))$ is an OT for all $n,m$. But $D_0(D_0(D_1(0))$ is not an OT.

Finally, the "relevant ordinal terms" are those OT's of the form $D_0(\cdots) + \cdots$. (Because $D_0$ corresponds to the collapsing function $\Psi_0$ that produces countable ordinals... nevermind.)

So the question is to give a direct proof that the set of relevant ordinal terms is WO under "$<$". **That's the end of the question.**

**To illustrate what I mean by a "self-contained proof",** here is a sketch of the proof that, if we limit the subscripts $n$ in $D_n$ to just $n=0$, then the set is WO. (In fact, these OT's correspond to the ordinals below $\varepsilon_0$.) Call the *height* of a term the height of the corresponding tree (i.e. length of the longest path from the root to a leaf). Note that if two OT's have different heights, then the one with the larger height will always be larger, and that the requirement regarding the sets $G_n$ in the definition of OT's is irrelevant, since it is always satisfied.

We prove by induction on the height $h$ that there is no infinite descending sequence of OT's of height $\le h$. Suppose this is true for height $\le h-1$, and let $\beta_1 > \beta_2 > \cdots$ be an infinite decreasing sequence in which $\beta_1$ has height $\le h$. Denote $\beta_i = \sum_j D_0(\alpha_{i,j}) \cdot m_{i,j}$ (grouping equal principal terms). Then the sequence $\alpha_{i,1}$ is nonincreasing, and it becomes constant at some point (by the induction assumption). Afterwards, the coefficient $m_{i,1}$ is nonincreasing and becomes constant at some later point. Afterwards, $\alpha_{i,2}$ is nonincreasing and becomes constant at some later point. And so on. We obtain an infinite decreasing sequence $\alpha_{i,1} > \alpha_{i,2} > \cdots$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Do you consider this result to be finitistic enough? https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82190282.pdf (Okada, "Note on a Proof of the Extended Kirby-Paris Theorem on Labeled Finite Trees".) I believe this proves that assuming consistency of $(\Pi_1^1-CA)+BI$, Buchholz's hydra game always terminates by relating the way Buchholz hydras expand with proof reductions in $(\Pi_1^1-CA)+BI$, whose proofs are all finite.